# "Call error 5" from Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Sometimes our GCS upload requests (from App Engine, if that matters) fail with the error "Call error 5".  I'm afraid I don't know the actual HTTP status code returned because we are using the [google-go-api-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/) which does some parsing of responses and (if the response is a JSON-formatted error message) only returns the error message itself in the returned error struct.

I presume that "Call error 5" indicates some kind of transient problem on Google's side, but I'd like to confirm this just to be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 10 MB per request and 32 MB per response. Please see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/#Go_Quotas_and_limits

Comment: That was indeed my error in this case - these all happened to be large (>10 MB) upload attempts.